# ASP.Net WebApi and KO Issue with Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am using EF in an ASP.Net MVC application and also using WebApi to get an element like so:

```
[HttpGet]
    public Student GetStudent(int id)
    {
        return db.Students.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Student_ID == id);
    }
```

This all works great and I map it directly into ko for use.  However when I bind the value of any DateTime properties of the element i.e. date of birth I get: 1955-04-17T11:13:56.  I don't want to change the web api methods or the model for every date, is there a 3rd party library or a knockout function that can handle a datetime from asp.net and correct the value for inputs.

Comment: you have to remap it to a `Date` object.

Comment: What do you want to get on client side? What's wrong with `1955-04-17T11:13:56`?

Comment: What's the problem? That looks like a valid date value.

Comment: Take a look at this [Scott Hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

Comment: You could use Moment.js for Date formatting. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, it's the format of the date and how best to get it as say 17-04-1955 in the input so that datepickers will work with the date as well.  I also want to do this through ko if possible so I don't have to add code for each date accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sridhar suggested in the comment. You can use moment.js to achieve this.

I've created a sample fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/ordwenj6/

Knockout code

```
function viewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.dateInput = ko.observable("1955-04-17T11:13:56");
    self.formattedDate = ko.computed(function(){
        var m = moment(self.dateInput());
        return m.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

HTML

```
<input data-bind="value : dateInput" />
<br/>
<span data-bind="text : formattedDate()" />
```

For demonstration, I've used the value from the input field for formatting. You can modify the code to use the value from the webapi and format it using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

**Update**

To do the same using ko custom binding handler, do the following

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateFormattedByMoment = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        $(element).val(moment(valueAccessor()).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<input id="customBinding" data-bind="dateFormattedByMoment : dateInput()" />
```

Working fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/ujh2cg73/

Comment: That does entail having to call the moment function on every date in the viewmodel which is what I want to avoid.  I assume I could put something similar to the above in a knockout custom binding so I can simply have something like:

    <input data-bind="dateFormattedByMoment: DOB" />

Comment: Yes. That is possible. Do you know how to create a custom binding handler? If yes, add the two lines of code in the binding handler.

Comment: I do but it was a while ago, will give it a go thanks.